# JavaScript IsFormDirty{ confirm()} is being ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like this is a simple answer but I have a block of JS and it loads when the page loads. The confirm() box popsup on IsFormDirty, but regardless of if i hit ok or cancel, it just cancels. Any help?

```
window.onunload = function () {
if (IsFormDirty) {

    if (confirm('Discard Unsaved Changes?')==false) {

        var form = $("div.tab-pane.active").find('form');
        form.validate();
        if (form.valid()) {
            $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(),
                function () {
                    refreshRebatePayments();
                }).fail(function (request) {
                    $('#dialog').html(request.responseText);
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#dialog");
                });

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your ajax doesn't finish before the page change happens, it gets aborted. this is one case where `async: false` is appropriate

Comment: @KevinB i don't think chrome support it in any way though

Comment: Yeah, i don't expect that confirm to work in all cases.

Comment: You'd have better to use onbeforeunload event instead. I guess more browser support for behaviour you are looking for, even AFAIK, there is no reliable cross browser way of doing this (of course using async false as suggested by Kevin)

Comment: Thank you all. I found that the problem was a JS runtime error that happened on a function before this function occurred. It is working properly now. (side note: I have to work in IE8 so the chrome issue is not a problem). THANKS AGAIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. I found that the problem was a JS runtime error that happened on a function before this function occurred. It is working properly now. (side note: I have to work in IE8 so the chrome issue is not a problem). THANKS AGAIN